# Can a C# property setter refer to an attribute on that same property?

Tags: c#, validation

I specify a property in a C# class.  I decorate it with a MaxLength attribute.

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Device Serial 
   /// </summary>
   [Required]
   [MaxLength(50)]
   public string TerId { get; set; }
```

Can I then modify it to use the value of the attribute inside a custom setter?

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Device Serial 
   /// </summary>
   [Required]
   [MaxLength(50)]
   public string TerId
   {
       get
       {
           return _terId;
       }
       set
       {
           if (value.Length <= this.TerId.MaxLengthAttribute)
           {
               _terId = value;
           }
           else
           {
               throw new ValidationException($"Max Length of Evidence.TerId would be exceeded by \"{value}\"");
           }
       }
   }
```

**this.TerId.MaxLengthAttribute** is an example.

I'm trying to catch some rogue data from a webservice that EF is throwing exceptions over.  I'd prefer to use the value rather than hardcode the length again.

Comment: There are plenty of ways of specifying a value once and reusing it, such as defining a `const`. Why, specifically, do you think you should hard code it in the attribute and then jump through hoops to retrieve it from there?

Comment: Using a simple const for that maxLength would be reasonable, and then use that const both as the Attribute's ctor parameter and in the setter validation.

If you for some reason want to read the attribute's value, it would go like `this.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(TerId)).GetCustomAttribute<MaxLengthAttribute>().Length`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding consts with length values for each string property

```
public class Device
{
    // Field lengths
    private const int _terIdLength = 50;
    // other length vars

    // Backing values
    private string _terId;
    // other backing values

    /// <summary>
    ///  device serial number
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(_terIdLength)]
    public string TerId
    {
        get
        {
            return _terId;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.Length <= _terIdLength)
            {
                _terId = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ValidationException($"Max Length of Device.TerId would be exceeded by \"{value}\"");
            }
        }
    }
    // other properties
}
```